# Eclipse: Linking source located in multiple subfolders of given folder

Tags: eclipse

I need to add external source code into my Eclipse project.
Project Properties>Java Build Path>"Link Source..." seems to be appropriate.

But it is necessary to add all the "source" folders of the folder that I link. It is a very complicated Folder structure, where "source" folders are located in different parent folders, but form the entire source code together. 
I just hate the idea to manually navigate to every folder and add it. "Inclusion patterns" feature in eclipse seems to be suitable for the task, but I can't get its syntax and how to specify inclusion to add all "source" subfolders.

Comment: What answer do you expect? What is the question?